# I want to make a printable Bible with a note section on each side

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2010

I want to make a printable Bible with a note section on each side of the text. I have made a template with text boxes to the right and left of the single column document. I have added Genesis CH 1 to the first page and it looks just like how I want it to look. The problem is I can't figure out how to get Word 2010 to open up another template for the so I can cut and paste Gen Ch 2 into the document. I want to do this with the whole bible and have it in one long document.

Comment: Why not just paste the whole thing, and apply wide left/right margins to the document instead of using textboxes?

Comment: In case you aren't aware of it, check out: [Xiphos](http://xiphos.org/) which is a complete bible study solution.  It does practically everything with every version of a bible.  The base doesn't include any bibles, the program will download the ones you select from within it.

Answer (score 1):

Format the page with wide margins on the left and right so it looks like a column down the middle.  Make the margins as wide as you need for your notes.  Create a text box in one of the margins that fills the notes area.  Create a one column table in it with as many rows as you need lines.  Use border formatting to create the horizontal lines.  Copy and paste the text box on the other side.  Now you have a template for all pages.